# webbrowser dll file

Tags: c#, dll, browser, custom-controls

I was wondering where on my computer I can find the dll file for the web browser control. The reason I need it is because I'd like to modify it for my own use, as I have found that being IE based, the webBrowser control doesn't give me everything I need, and I need to add various functions. Where can I find the dll for it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> the webBrowser control doesn't give me everything I need, and I need to add various functions

[Webkit](http://webkit.org/%5d)

should have everything you need. Since you're programming in C#, use a wrapper such as http://sourceforge.net/projects/webkitdotnet/ to add it to your form.

Answer (score 0):

`System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser` is located in `System.Windows.Forms.dll` but this class is only the wrapper over IE engine, installed in the system. So you can't modify it as you need.
 If you want to add your code, i advice to look on others engines, such as WebKit

Comment: @Ivan is WebKit the most basic? I would like the most basic one, but many of the ones I've found are pretty sophisticated. The closest I've found is awesomium (awesomium.com), but I'd like to be able to modify the control itself.... Sorry if my question is unclear! :S

Comment: In my opinion, Webkit is even more powerful, than IE. so i can't say it is the most basic.
Finally, it depends on what do you need from engine.

Comment: @Ivan, all I need is a "barebones" control, with the ability to add my own behavior when I need it. For example css-injection.

Comment: Do you want to include your custom styles to loaded pages? Maybe it is better to make a class proxy, which will process page source?

Comment: @IvanManzhos, that's probably what I'm going to do. I've started working with webkit, and hopefully I'll be done with my project soon! :D